# Popover changes in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, ipad, popover, ios5

I have just developed an iPad app to the point of testing, but did it in iOS 4.3. Now I've updated to 5.0 in the simulator and also went through Apple's steps to test on my iPad which runs 5.0

In the 4.3 simulator all works fine. But in the 5.0 simulator and on the iPad all of my popovers that originate from UIButtons crash the app. I have a popover coming from a navbar button which works fine.

Each popover that crashes will display its contents (a UIWebview with a pdf file), but when I then click anywhere on the screen the app crashes (within the popover and outside).

I can post some code, but hope that this description helps give someone an idea. I don't manually dismiss the popover or check if it is open, but since this doesn't only occur by trying to touch its launching UIButton I don't think that's why it's happening. Plus it works as is under 4.3

---

Edit: This is solved now thanks to Stephen's comment. I added into the popOver's content viewController:

```
- (void) dealloc {
 [webView release];
 [super release];
}
```

Usually I would call `[super dealloc]` instead of `[super release]`, but `[super dealloc]` didn't fix the exception (exc_bad_access). Hopefully I haven't put a sloppy patch on the problem!

Comment: What exception? What's the stack trace? This is most probably a memory management problem.

Comment: I'm guessing it takes a lovely storage fault with no traceback.  (And of course the iOS 5 simulator wouldn't provide a traceback anyway.)

Comment: Thank you Stephen, you were bang on with the memory management. I had to put in the dealloc method and let super release too. Since it worked on the 4.3 simulator that didn't even occur to me. I was only releasing in the same method that I alloc'd the webView for the popover contents.

Comment: Doing `[super release]` makes no sense -- it's no different from doing `[self release]`, and presumably the object is already released or else `dealloc` would not be called.  I suspect you've just kicked the can down the road a bit.

Comment: I agree with Hot Licks. calling `[super release]` in `-dealloc` is absolutely the wrong thing.  Not calling `[super dealloc]` in a `-dealloc` method is a memory leak and should be giving you a compiler warning. If putting in `[super dealloc]` is causing you crashes, then perhaps you should fix *those* problems instead...

Answer (score 0):

I had a thread started to collect bugs like this, but the forum police quashed it.  Suffice it to say that iOS 5 is riddled with incompatibilities.

I can't say with any certainty what your problem is, but there's a good chance it has to do with the changes to UINavigationController, which caused UIViewController's navigationController to be nil for popups, with parentViewController taking its place.

Unfortunately, parentViewController is new, so you must, eg, test `respondsToSelector:@selector(parentViewController)` and take parentViewController if it exists, otherwise navigationController.

Had to add this logic in about 30 places in an app we have.